# Load Julia modules on demand

Tags: matplotlib, julia

I I have a very simple question. Is it possible to load modules on demand in Julia. That is, can the modules be loaded when they are actually needed instead of being loaded at "parse-time" at the top level.

The use case scenario I have in mind is that I have some set of code that is able to do some plotting using PyPlot, but code is far from always executed.

At the moment this means that I have at top level a statement like `using PyPlot`, which takes quite a load of time to load.

(Yes i know: One should not restart Julia to often, bla bla bla... but nevertheless this is a point of annoyance)

Is there a way to ensure that PyPlot is only loaded is if is actually needed?
The simplest idea would have been to include the `using PyPlot` inside the function that actually do the plotting

```
function my_plot()
    using PyPlot
    plot(1:10,1:10)
end
```

but this results in a syntax error:

```
ERROR: syntax: "using" expression not at top level
```

So, is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: you could `eval` that `using` expr in the global scope.

Comment: @Gnimuc Thanks for your comment but i don't understand what you mean. Could you possibly give an example?

Comment: add `@eval` before `using PyPlot`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "using" statement runs when the line of code is encountered, and does not have to be at the top of the file.  It does need to be in global scope, which means that the variables in the module loaded with "using" will be available to all functions in your program after the "using" statement is executed, not just a single function as might happen in the local scope of a function.

If you call the using statement as an expression within a Julia eval statement, all code executed within the "eval" statement in Julia is automatically done so in global scope, even if the eval is syntactically called within a function's local scope. So if you use the macro @eval

```
function my_plot()
    @eval using PyPlot  # or without the macro, as eval(:(using PyPlot))
    plot(1:10,1:10)
end
```

this acts as if the using PyPlot is done outside a function, and so avoids the syntax error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However now new problems arise. When i put the `@eval` in a function then it's cant find PyPlot anyway: I have: `@eval using PyPlot ; clf()` and get "ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching clf()
The applicable method may be too new: running in world age 25167, while current world is 25173." At some other place in the code i have aleary run `using PyCall` is this why i still get a clash?

Comment: clf() is a PyPlot function. The error message means that code that refers to PyPlot routines is compiled before the using PyPlot was run. You could find the function generatingthe error and run the using statement before that code is encountered, but since this might not be resilient to refactoring your code further, getting this error means you should just run PyPlot at the top.,

Comment: I should add that sometimes specifying clf to be PyCall,clf() in the code where the call to clf() is made might also work since PyPlot() might be changing the reference of clf() from PyCall.clf to PyPlot.clf() as program runs.